# Extract raster attribute other than value to points in ArcGIS Pro using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst

I have a raster with two attributes, Value and Category. I would like to extract the Category to points. I am using Extract Multi Values to Points, but this always defaults to the Value attribute. Is it possible to extract other attributes?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you are working with. That way we will be able to see the behavior you’re describing. Also if you have any site specific questions or problems please flag the post for a moderators attention rather than communicating through the question.

Comment: You say "who cares what I write this here", well the community you reached out to for help...

Comment: Could also use the Lookup tool

Answer (score 2):

Extract values I believe only works with the value of the cell, but you can simply join the category in your raster attribute table to the point dataset, using the value as the joining field to help pass over the category field.  You do this by using the [Join Field tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/join-field.htm).